# AWS ELB 502 at the same time every day

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

First some insight into how my setup is:

- 1 ELB
- 4 EC2 instances

  - 2 web servers
  - 1 to run the migrations, queue (beanstalkd) and scheduler
  - 1 'services' server (socket.io instance etc etc)
- MySQL on RDS
- Redis on Elasticache
- S3 for user assets

Every day at 10:55PM, users report getting white screens and 502 Bad Gateway errors. The ELB reports that both EC2 instances are OutOfService, yet I'm SSH'd into them and fully able to use the site by bypassing the ELB. RDS and Elasticache maintenance windows aren't during this period, and the two instances aren't at load either. I can't find anything in the ELB access logs, nothing in nginx logs on the instance end, nothing in the Laravel app logs. There's nothing in the Laravel scheduler that runs at this time either.

The only thing I've found, is that in my CloudWatch metrics, the ELB latency spikes right up to about 5-10 seconds. All this results in downtime of about 5-15 minutes at the same time every day. I can't seem to find anything that is causing the issue.

I'm 100% stumped as to what could be causing this to happen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ELB instances are OutOfService - thats the biggest clue. How are the ELB health check configured? You need to start looking at that health check page and how the health check page returns status 200 or 4xx or 5xx. That where the problem lies.

Comment: Ping Target: HTTP:80/, Timeout: 10 seconds, Interval: 30 seconds, Unhealthy Threshold: 6, Healthy Threshold: 10. Then in CloudWatch, it's a bunch of HTTP 5xx and ELB 5xx statuses at the time. Even though I can access the site directly by bypassing the ELB, which is why it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: you mean to say - the you can access the web application during 5 to 15 mins of downtime via. by-passing the ELB and hitting the EC2 instance ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, if I wasn't making sense, sorry. I was also SSH'd into both instances while monitoring `top` and I never got disconnected or anything.

Comment: Whats do the maximum statistic graphs look like for the two instances - CPU, NetworkIn, NetworkOut, StatusCheck_Failed?

Comment: Bottom two are the maximum graphs, top two are averages I already had up: http://i.imgur.com/wpHLaDE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What probably happens is that your web servers run out of connections, ELB cannot perform health checks and takes them out of service. It's actually enough for one of the machines to experience this and be taken out of service and the other will be killed as a cascading effect.

How many connections can the web servers hold at the same time? 
Do you process a particularly "heavy request" at that point in time when this happens?
Does adding more web servers solve your problem?

Comment: Max connections: I have no idea, honestly.

Heavy request: No. 5 minutes later than it starts? Yes, but thats what the queue server is for and that never goes over like 5% CPU load.

More servers: Not sure, I will try this tonight. Costs are already pretty high :/

Comment: would either watch for heavy load (a lot of requests or long running requests). What web server are you using?

Comment: Nginx. Web instances are provisioned and managed with Laravel Forge. I've put a third web instance up to see if it happens again tonight, and I'll have to monitor live traffic or something. I was watching prod1 and prod2 in `top` and everything was normal.

Comment: Forge disables access logs by default, so I had to enable them. It's now 11:40PM and the site didn't go down, so I'm assuming it indeed was a traffic issue as adding another web server seemed to do the job. Thanks for the help and steering me in the right direction.